# How to use cypress plugins in version 10

Tags: javascript, cypress

When using [htmlvalidate](https://html-validate.org/usage/cypress.html) with [cypress](https://cypress.io) (version 9 or less) you can simply install via `cypress/plugins/index.js:`:

```
const htmlvalidate = require("cypress-html-validate/dist/plugin");

module.exports = (on) => {
  htmlvalidate.install(on);
};
```

However plugins was depreciated in cypress version 10 and you need to use [config](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide#Using-a-plugin).

However it's not clear to me how to enable htmlvalidator in this manner. E.g:

```
const {defineConfig} = require('cypress');
const {htmlvalidate} = require("cypress-html-validate/dist/plugin");

module.exports = defineConfig({
    projectId: '4dofbo',
    e2e: {

        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            on('task', {
                // WHAT GOES HERE?
            });
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: And that's why the Cypress team wrote [a migration guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Plugins-File-Removed) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to utilize any `on('task')` function, and instead can use the function in `setupNodeEvents`.

Directly from the [`cypress-html-validate` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-html-validate#usage)

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      htmlvalidate.install(on);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when adding `import htmlvalidate from "cypress-html-validate/plugin";` to `cypress.config.js`?

Comment: Why not use your existing import? `const {htmlvalidate} = require("cypress-html-validate/dist/plugin");`